# Active Admin accessing two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I would like to access the data from the Profile using Active Admin.

Profile has this model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :name, :phone
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Print (orders) has this model:

```
class Print < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....

  belongs_to :user
  has_one :profile
...
end
```

Both models have user_id column in it, from the User model.
and the Print (Orders) print.rb is written as:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Print, :as => "Order" do

     index do
      column "Document", :document_file_name do |print|
         link_to print.document_file_name, print.document.url
      end
      column "Size", :document_file_size do |print|
            number_to_human_size(print.document_file_size)
      end
      column "Print Status", :is_printing
      column "Deliver Status", :is_delivered
      column "Comments", :comment
      default_actions
     end

     show do
       panel "Invoice" do
        table_for(order.user.profile) do
          column "name" do |profile|
           profile.name
          end
        end
       end
     end

end
```

How do i get the data from profile, for example, :address  from Active Admin?

EDIT:

I am sharing my solution since someone requested for it:

```
sidebar "Customer Details", :only => :show do
   attributes_table_for customer.profile do
      row("Email") { customer.email }
      row("Name") { auto_link customer.profile.name }
      row("Address") { auto_link customer.profile.address }
      row("Phone") { auto_link customer.profile.phone }
    end
 end
```

Comment: Which version of ruby on rails do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
column :address do |order|
 order.user.address
end
```

Comment: How about the tables_for? I had tried order.user.profile but it doesn't work, giving an error:

undefined method `each' for #<Profile:0x007f8ab8106130>

Comment: Instead of table_for why dont you use  attributes_table  `do
      row user.address  end `

Comment: i use attributes_table_for order.use.profile do

row("Name") { order.user.profile.name }

Comment: @muhammadn, can you please write a full code of how you solved the issue?

Comment: Hi oscar, i have provided the full code on how i solved the issue. Hope it helps you. :)